# Can you use google's Chrome on Raspberry 3 with Raspbian (not Chromium)?

Tags: raspbian, security, google-chrome

I would like to know: can one use Google Chrome (not Chromium) on a Raspberry 3 running Raspbian or is it too heavy for the Pi 3?

The reason is that I would like to get the **more frequent** and **automatic** updates by Google.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The only method i know is [this](https://eltechs.com/run-google-chrome-on-raspberry-pi/), but you have to pay for the exagear softwere that let you run x86 applications on ARM-based mini PCs. Otherwise is not possible
, you can see more on the [Raspberry pi forums.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=145741)
It's a bummer but Chromium is almost chrome.